# Is it true in general that $E_Z(E(Y\mid X, Z)) = E(Y\mid X)$ in that conditioning variables can be removed one by one?

Tags: probability

I am wondering if it is generally the case that

$$
E_Z(E(Y\mid X, Z))  = E(Y\mid X)
$$

in that conditioning variables can be removed one by one? I know that

$$
E(E(Y\mid X, Z)\mid X)  = E(Y\mid X)
$$

is generally true, but can one selected which variables that are being conditioned on to marginalize over?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the first equality ? In general the result of an expectation is not a random variable.

Comment: If $E_Z$ stands for conditional expectation given $Z$ then this is false.

Comment: I meant $E_Z$ to stand for the marginal expectation with respect to $Z$, such that $E_Z(Z) = \int z f_Z(z) dz$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right. Here is my proof.

\begin{align}
E(Y|X) & = \sum_{y} y P(Y=y|X) \\
& = \sum_{y} \sum_z y P(Y=y,Z=z|X) \\
& = \sum_{y} \sum_z y P(Y=y| Z=z,X) P(Z) \\
& = E_z \left[\sum_{y} y P(Y=y| Z=z,X) \right] \\
& = E_z \left[E(Y|Z,X) \right]
\end{align}

Comment: The third line should be: $$=\sum\limits_y~\sum\limits_z~y~P(Y{=}y\mid Z{=}z; X)~P(Z{=}z\mid X)$$ Thus $$\mathsf E(Y\mid X)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid Z,X)\mid X)$$ Now, *if* $X,Z$ are independent, *then* $\mathsf P(Z{=}z\mid X{=}x)=\mathsf P(Z{=}z)$ .